# memory management, should release be used in this case?

Tags: objective-c

Given the following code snippet from inside a method;

```
NSBezierPath * tempPath = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:pathRect];
            [tempPath retain];
            [path release];
            [self setPath:tempPath];
```

Am I responsible for releasing `tempPath` or will it be done for me? 

The setPath is `@synthesize`d so I probably would be able to leave out the `[path release]` as well?

I know the better way of doing this is simply;

```
[path appendBezierPathWithOvalInRect:pathRect];
```

But, being new to Objective C and Cocoa, I'm trying to understand how things stick together.


---ADDED CONTENT
Leaving out the `[tempPath retain]` results in a crash in the `NSView` object that uses the paths. 
The result from the debugger:

> ```
> (gdb) po [0x145dc0 path]
>
> Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access
> ```
>
> memory.
>       Reason: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at address: 0x00000021
>       0x93c56688 in objc_msgSend ()

**CONFESSION OF GUILT** - my mistake. Hope someone else will get something useful from my mistake. I had used `assign` in place of `retain` in the `@property` declaration. Fixing those made the code work as  expected.

THANKS FOR THE HELP GUYS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `path` is the instance variable backing the `-setPath:` method then no, you absolutely should not be releasing it outside of your `-dealloc` method. You don't need to manually retain your `tempPath` object since you're using an accessor to save that object. Your accessors, `-setPath:` in this case, `-init` and `-dealloc` methods should be the only methods where you'd be calling `-retain` and `-release` on your instance variables.

Your code works just as well like this, and with less chance of a memory leak:

```
NSBezierPath *tempPath = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:pathRect];
[self setPath:tempPath];
```

Since the `-bezierPathWithOvalInRect:` method returns an autoreleased object and your accessor will retain it you don't need to do anything else with it.

Comment: Thanks Ashley. If I leave out the retain, the program crashes later on in an NSView object that uses the paths.

Comment: @Ashley: How did you know that NSBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect: returned an autoreleased object?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to release tempPath.

You can also drop the `[tempPath retain]` and the `[path release]`.  These are taken care of by synthesizing the set method.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at this another way:

If you weren't using synthesized accessors, you'd be writing them yourself. In their simplest forms they would look like this:

```
- (NSBezierPath *) path {
    return path;
}

- (void)setPath:(NSBezierPath *)newPath {
    if (path == newPath) {
        // both objects have the same pointer so are the same.
        return;
    }

    [path release];
    path = [newPath retain];
}
```

You can see that the old path is released and the new path is retained within the setter, so you do not need to do this from within your method which can be written as

```
self.path = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:pathRect];
```